# remove "users" prefix on devise 1.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, routes

I have this in routes.rb:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks" }
```

I want remove the users prefix that devise have by default,**users/sign_up**, **users/login**, **users/secret/new**,...etc

If I put this:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks" }, :path => '/'
```

I get the next error:

**RuntimeError
You can only add :omniauthable behavior to one Devise model**

Comment: The response is in https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Change-the-default-sign_in-and-sign_out-routes. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have `devise_for :users` only once in your routes file. Otherwise it thinks you're trying to use omniauth on two models and "Currently, Devise only allows you to make one model omniauthable".